# Can't upload two different framework websites on a server

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

I am trying to upload two different framework(2.0 and 4.0) websites on a server.

If iis target framework 4.0 is enabled then my website 2.0 shows the error: `Server Application Unavailable`

If iis target framework 2.0 is enabled then my website 4.0 shows an error

```
Unrecognized attribute target Framework. 
 Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit1

The problem can be `Framework`. As it is case sensitive 
You can set the framework as follows

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

### Old

You need to create different application pool.
One application pool should be using `framework 2.0`
and another should be using `framework 4.0`
Apply in both the application accordingly.

Here is a good link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0

[MSDN Article link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An IIS application can only run under one framework.  Each application however is assigned to an application pool which determines what version of the framework to run.

You can simply create a new application pool that works with a different version of the framework.

See the [MS Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on details for how to do this.

From the article for IIS7:

1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
2. In the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
3. On the Application Pools page, in the Actions pane, click Add Application Pool.
4. On the Add Application Pool dialog box, type a friendly name for the application pool in the Name box.
5. From the .NET Framework version list, select the version of the .NET Framework required by your managed applications, modules, and handlers. Or select No Managed Code if the applications that you run in this application pool do not require the .NET Framework.
6. From the Managed pipeline mode list, select one of the following options:

   - Integrated, if you want to use the integrated IIS and ASP.NET request- processing pipeline.
   - Classic, if you want to use IIS and ASP.NET request-processing modes separately. In classic mode, managed code is processed by using Aspnet_isapi.dll instead of the IIS 7 integrated pipeline.
7. Select Start application pool immediately to start the application pool whenever the WWW service is started. By default, this is selected.
8. Click OK.